# Declined comment flag for obsolete comment

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments, flagging

This answer:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/57925/874

gathered an excellent comment by @Mackk, which included a link to a video.  I thought that the video would enhance the answer greatly, so I submitted an edit to add the video into the answer.  The edit, which credited @Mackk, was accepted.

I then flagged the comment as being obsolete, since the comment was now included in the answer.  The flag was rejected.  Since the video in the comment is now in the answer, and the answer credits Mackk, why was the flag rejected?  Was it just an oversight by the mod, or a misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was the one declining.

Sorry, but the flagged comment interface does not show the answer the comment is attached to, and I remembered the comment and the original answer, so I neglected checking if the answer got edited, since many many users flag such comments even if they are still needed.

So, sorry, this was an honest mistake, I should have accepted your flag and deleted the comment.

I'll give you time to flag it again before I delete the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It's an honest mistake, so no worries at all.  I'll flag the comment again in a bit.  For next time, would it be more helpful to mods if I gave a custom reason explaining in more detail why the comment was obsolete?

Comment: @WayneConrad in the specific case (1 comment alone) yes, something like "video incorporated in answer" would help. it is not needed when there are many comments and you flag them all, at that point is clear that it is a discussion in need of cleaning.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the help, and thanks for moderating in general.